# Render/show reusable views in view controllers view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is it possible to design reusable views that are subclasses of UIView, and then drag an instance of UIView onto the view for a view controller in storyboard, change its type to whatever the reusable view is and then see it?

Edit:

This is my BaseView:

[image]

And this is my view controllers view where I use it:

[image]

I must do this inside BaseView:

```
func customInit() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    insertSubview(view, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Because with addSubview it appears over everything, it seems to be added last. But I don't know why.

Comment: are you asking us about `@IBDesignable` views?

Comment: I don't know what it is named. I have a custom view named `BaseView` at this moment that I want to add some UI components too, then on all view controllers view change the main view type to `BaseView` and see it.

Comment: okay, we are on the spot; it is called _designable view_ and such views marked by `@IBDesignable` keywords in code and probably you can find hundreds of lovely tutorials of how to create such views; they will reflect every changes in IB, mostly used together with `@IBInspectable` properties to make the view configurable via IB directly.

Comment: I have added @IBDesignable to the `BaseView` that I created, I then dragged a UIView to a view controllers view, changed its type to `BaseView` but still I don't see it renders. Do I have to use preview mode?

Comment: you need to override the `-drawRect:` method, perhaps, or use the `-didMoveToSuperview` method to set up / dismiss the basic layout.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1st concept

that is a nice example for creating standalone designable views *without* `xib` file.

I could not make it too specific for you as you asked a random sample only, which looks pretty much like this.

#### RandomView.swift

```
import UIKit;

//

@IBDesignable

@objc class RandomView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var borderRadius: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var borderColour: UIColor? = nil

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if self.superview != nil {
            // build up layout
            self.borderColour = UIColor.redColor()
        } else {
            // /dismiss it
            self.borderColour = nil
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        // draw the layout

        self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.borderRadius

        if let color: UIColor = borderColour {
            self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
        } else {
            self.layer.borderColor = nil
        }
    }

}
```

#### then

you can add that a new `UIView` to your main view, and for that particular class you can set the custom class explicitly into IB:

[image: explicit class]

the IB updates the attributes panel, and now you can change the border width / radius / colour for each individual instance you would put into your view and the changes affects immediately:

[image: appearance]

---

## 2nd concept

this concept requires to create the `xib` file as well, so actually we will have two files and in the `xib` you can build up your custom interface as usual.

#### RandomView.xib

this is how it looks, it might be important to set up the *File's Owner* as `RandomView`, but everything else is just the regular business here, I have added only a single a `UILabel` to the middle of the custom view.

[image: the custom view]

#### RandomView.swift

```
import UIKit;

//

@IBDesignable

@objc class RandomView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var title: NSString? {
        set (newValue) {
            if self.customLabel != nil {
                self.customLabel!.text = newValue as? String
            }
        }
        get {
            if self.customLabel != nil {
                return self.customLabel!.text
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var customLabel: UILabel? = nil

    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customInit()
    }

    func customInit() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight] // quick soliution
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "RandomView", bundle: bundle) // get xib name correctly!
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

}
```

now you can put this new view into any other interface, like:

[image: added as subview]

my view look like this with one `UILabel` at the middle of the view (using auto-layout and constraints in the `xib`), so actually that creates a kinda *"preview"* of the designable view in IB:

[image: changing inspectable values]

---

*NOTE: obviously you don't need to make inspectable properties, you can hardcode everything, even adding extra subviews or whatever you actually need for your interface, but the basic concept would be that simple.*

Comment: Okey, but this is a little bit different from what I am doing and wanted to do. I have a XiB file that is named `BaseView` and I have a subclass of UIView named `BaseView`. In interface builder I have dragged a UIImageView onto the `BaseView` so it covers the whole view. After that I want to use and view that BaseView in other view controller views. Is that possible? I haven't changed anything in drawRect: etc.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean, bear with me.

Comment: Thank you. My english is not so good. But essentially what I want is the same as I did in Netbeans with Java. Created small Swing components in the designer and I could then use those components to build more advanced components.

Comment: Do you know how to do it?

Comment: yes... it is kinda hard to edit the answer and put together everything, but I guess the 2nd concept you are looking for in my answer; however I don't know NetBeans at all, or how that works.

Comment: Sweeet! That almost looks right now. The only thing now is that the subview of BaseView (which is an ImageView) covers everything. Decreasing the alpha to 0.5, I am able to see the content below.

Comment: Changing `addSubview` to `insertSubview` at index 0 fixes it, but I am a little bit unsure why.

Comment: if you insert the subview at index `0`, that means it will be behind everything; which is just the complete opposite than the `addSubview()` does.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't understand why calling `subviews.count` inside `customInit` returns 4 when I use the `BaseView` inside the view of my view controller. I expected it to have nothing at that point?

Comment: it is supposed to be `0` before the `loadViewFromNib()` is called unless you have added 4 other views to your view in the interface builder.

Comment: okay... I see, but you have not created a custom `xib`for your class, you just literally added directly some plus views to it... that is what I suggested to do in my answer at all.

Comment: I have created custom XiB too. The BaseView has a XiB where I have added a UIImageView in InterfaceBuilder. It is a background view that I want on every base view. Then I set the BaseView as type of view controllers view.

Comment: Yes, we have done exactly the same now. But I have added contents inside the `BaseView` which is the same as your `RandomView` in the view of the viewcontroller where I use it. Thats the reason I get 4 subviews; 2 of them are the guides and the other two are tableview and view. They must be the content of the NSCoder instance passed to the init-method.

Comment: I have __not__ added any subview to the `RandomView`; the `UILabel` is part of the designable `xib` file as you can see my `RandomView` has `0` (zero) subviews when I added it to my main view (which also holds an independent segmented controller, but they are sibling only) – if I add subviews obviously I would have custom subviews inside only that particular instance but not inside the original `RandomView`, if you need to add more subviews, obviously they will be there, that is why your subview counter shows `4`, but that that is because you added those subviews explicitly.

Comment: I am not stating that you have either, do I? I say I have done that, added content to the BaseView on purpose. It is all working and I know why so everything is fine.

Comment: you said you have already `4` subviews... those subview are not appearing randomly, as on my screen there is no subview at all, I have `0` – but I have not add any, you need to delete your subviews if you don't want to see `0` subviews. :)

Comment: But those subviews are from the view controller, where I use the BaseView and add views to it so it is all fine

Comment: I am not familiar with your view hierarchy, but I can tell you basically in the `customInit()` method you are supposed to see `0` subviews; if you add any subviews to your designable view on your main layout, that number won't be `0`, but the reason why we created such _designable-views_ was exactly that you don't need to add any extra subview to the _designable-view_ but reuse it only as many times as you need on your main layout; otherwise the _designable-view_ might lose its entire purpose and everything we did here was just too much ado for nothing. :(

Comment: Yes, I understood that after some thinking and looking at the code. No, not completly because my use case is this: I have made an application where I have a background image that I want to apply to ALL views. Instead of dragging an UIImageView and setting the properties in every view controller I can now just change the type of the `view` of the view controller to `BaseView` and I get that background. If I want to change it later I can easly do that for all views.

Comment: But other than that, yes I understand what you mean. But I think the use case I describe is an exception that makes it worth it.

Comment: you can customise the view freely, I just want to be sure I gave you the proper idea of the concept but it is up to you how you'd like to improve it for your current case. :)